# Grunt - Unable to compile less to css using grunt-contrib-less

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-less

I've a good feeling i am doing something extremely silly here but i am not sure what.

I am using `grunt-contrib-less` to compile less into css but it just doesn't seem to work at all. It shows no error or does anything and i am not sure why.

please find the JSBIN here - http://jsbin.com/hagavokige/edit?html,js

If you prefer Gist then - https://gist.github.com/ktkaushik/b3fc7aa4445e88c46bdf

I could really use some help here. I've been stuck at this one for long.

I am also using -

**Using grunt v0.4.5**

**Using node v5.1.1**

**Using npm v3.312**

***update 1***

There is NO output at all. I event added the `--debug` flag in the CLI but no luck.

Comment: what is the output of `grunt less`?

Comment: there is no output at all. It doesn't do anything.

Comment: can it be that the src should be an array. I am not sure as it is not obvious from the documentation, but...

Comment: @eesdil tried that after i read your comment. Sadly, that's not it though.

Comment: I have a good feeling it's something really silly. I thought it could be the version of Grunt as well but perhaps that's not it.

Comment: you have somehow infinite call of the compilation... just dont know why... grunt less --verbose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haha :)

rename your "less" task to different name like myLess, as it is running the main less tasks, so it is creating infinite loop

https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-less/issues/279

Comment: Brilliant ! Thanks @eesdil. _i did'nt know --verbose_ so thanks for that too :)

Comment: this is now in the Readme so that no one ever spends more than 5 minutes debugging this issue in the future. https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-less/pull/301#event-521723780